# Master thesis grade

Tags: thesis, masters, software

I am not happy with my master thesis grade. I wrote down my master thesis in a company. I had three supervisors in this 6 month period, two of them from university and one of them from the company. I worked three days of the week in the company (my task is implementing of an app) and other days I focused on my report. I made all the corrections in the report that  my supervisors offered and went to the meetings regularly. I feel really disappointed to grade (2.7); I expected to get 2.0.

How should I explain my ideas to the assistants and what should be the first step? On the other hand, I am really angry and I could not even thinking about the subject in a healthy way. I need to some professional ideas or someone who had the same experience before.

Edit: The company found this chair to me and they have still contact and they are making projects in cooperation. I saw my grade in online system, I have not yet got my diploma.

Edit: The sign of the good work (I presented my work also in the company after making the presentation in university and they liked the results.) Also some of the colloquies of the company think as same as me that I deserve better than 2.7.

Comment: I don't understand: have you already graduated? If so, why do you still need to explain your ideas to assistants? In addition, which country are you?

Comment: Was the cooperation between the company and the university for your thesis proposed by the university or did you organize it? From personal experience I can say that some universities don't like their students doing work for companies when they could as well work for them exclusively. That *could* manifest in a bad grade, which certainly is unfair. How does your grade compare to other students'?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear (well, what are your ideas? Did you get any signs that your work was good, better than just good or mediocre? Why did you expect a 2.0?) but here are some thoughts: Relax and don't hurry. Hard work does not necessarily lead to good grades. Neither does doing everything that you are told to do. Don't look back but focus on the future. Unless there did something outrageous happen, it is usually next to impossible to change a grade. Ask for explanation as for why you got this grade, listen carefully and try to learn.

Comment: I don't think "assistants" s the word you are looking for. Possibly Advisors, Supervisiors,  Or Assessors, Examiners?

Comment: Was your thesis done in English, or another language?

Comment: I am not sure I understand  2.0 is better than 2.7. Would you explain a little bit how the thesis is supposed to be graded?

Comment: @scaaahu I think this is German grading

Answer (score 4):

For a start, you should ask your two university supervisors whether you can have some feedback on your work. I do not mean a bare grade, but an extended discussion of good aspects and bad aspects that formed the basis for the grade. Most Bachelor/Master thesis supervisors I encountered routinely offer that to their students, anyway.

If you really disagree with their assessment, you can take it to the respective professor (unless he or she was already included in the aforementioned "supervisors"), but the professor might know quite a bit less about how you worked than your direct supervisors.

These are usually your primary ways to go to - but I would also like to discuss some statements you made about your impression of your work:

> I made all the corrections in the report that my supervisors offered and went to the meeting regularly.

This is not a guarantee for a good mark. For a start, I have had many students tell me they "made all the corrections", with very varying results. Furthermore, you making all suggested corrections may mean a solid result, but it is still not as good as if you had found some of the opportunities for corrections on your own. Coming back to the first point, it is very possible your supervisors were only explicit about corrections to make your work acceptable, which is a long way from making it excellent.

> Also some of the colloquies of the company think as same as me that I deserve better than 2.7.

People in the industry (even if they went to uni themselves) often have a surprisingly bad grasp of what a university might expect from a graduation thesis. This might be reflected in (your summary of) your task "my task is implementing of an app", which appears to feature no conceptual/research aspect (or maybe you just did not realize?), and also by your statement that you wrote your report at the university and implemented at the company at the stated ratio. Therefore, your company colleagues may well have found you a capable coder, but that doesn't mean that the entirety of the thesis fully lived up to the expectations of the university.

Answer (score 0):

I think most universities will have formal procedures for lodging a complaint and requesting a reassessment. I would think this would probably be a tiered process. First you ask for a written assessment of your work, so you can decide wether or not you agree with the examiner. If not, you can request the examiner to reassess. If still not happy, you can probably request a new assessment by a new examiner. However, you might end up with the same or a worse result.